# Laravel session automatically extended by an Ajax call?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a tiny JS script running in an interval:

```
<script>
    function checkAuthState() {
        $.get('/session/check', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    setInterval(checkAuthState, 10000);
</script>
```

The controller action is - currently - a dummy one:

```
<?php

    public function checkAuthState() {
        return response()->json(array('success' => true));
    }
```

What I've noticed, is that the `laravel_session` cookie expiry date **gets extended automatically every time the Ajax call is made** - by 10 seconds (which matches the JS interval).

Why does this happen?

I need to add a handler for the case when the session expires, but apparently hitting the server every 10 seconds prevents (?) it. I'm confused.

Important settings in my **session.php** config:

```
'lifetime' => 1, /* 1 min, for testing purposes */
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session expires when it looks like the vistor has left the site and gone away. This is assumed to be "A certain amount of time after they last made a request to the site".

An Ajax request is a request (like any other as far as the server is concerned), so the cookie is extended as it would be for any other request.

Comment: Honestly and with a bit of shame -- I had no idea this is how it worked. Doesn't this mean that if there are other background calls made all the time, the session never expires, even if the user is long gone?

Comment: For a value of "gone" that includes "Has a browser window open and pointing at the website", yes.

Comment: I marked this answer as *best*, as it clearly addresses my original, central question: *Why does this happen?* Still, thanks to Alexey Mezenin for his input and examples.

Answer (score 2):

That's how session works. If you want to store some data that should expire, use [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache) instead. Store the data for one minute:

```
cache(['key' => 'value'], 1);
```

Then use it:

```
public function checkAuthState()
{
    cache('key');
    return response()->json(array('success' => true));
}
```

**Update**

If you want to find out if session expired or not, just store some value:

```
session('key', 'value')
```

And check it:

```
if (session('key'))
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea is (or rather *was*) to have a call made every 10 seconds to make sure the session did not expire. If it did, I'd show a popup and reload the page. However, if the call to check the session actually extends the session... What's the alternative? (I will just say I can't afford a web socket server for now)

Comment: That's simple enough. But if I want to show a popup on the client side, I'd still need to call the server to check if the `session('key')` exists or not -- which brings me back to extending the session unintentionally.

Comment: @lesssugar well, you have no choice here, you need to check it or use 
 broadcasting (web sockets). You could also, remember the time and check it in front-end part of the app, but it's not robust solution.

Comment: Yep, I feel a pivot coming. Thanks again for the suggestions and the time spent.